# openstack install command line with proxy setup

Tags: juju, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

As per Ubuntu WIKI - Single Install

```
For Proxy Issues:
If you are behind a firewall that requires use of an http/s proxy, be sure 
you set that up in your install command line.
```

What are the openstack Install command line with proxy for below deployments...Thank you

```
1. Autopilot - The Canonical Distribution - Enterprise Openstack Install and Management
2. Multi - OPenstack installation utilizing MAAS
3. Single - Fully containerized Openstack installation on a single Machine
```

Answer (score 0):

In general proxies are set on the command line as follows, specifying proxyname and port

export http_proxy=http://myproxy.mynet.net:80
export ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.mynet.net:80
export https_proxy=http://myproxy.mynet.net:80

unsure how the openstack installer ready proxy settings though